# invalid host header Heroku node.js react app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku

My heroku app is a react app. I am running into an issue of invalid host header.

The first thing i tried to do was make a .env.development folder but I may have set it up wrong. If anyone has any suggestions please let me know.

The repo is on github at https://github.com/syne612/projectIcarusWebsite if anyone has any suggestions please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might lie in the proxy you set the package.json in the client.

Try to remove that and restart the server.

For further info: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development